# How to make post request in contact form 7 in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, post, contact-form-7

I installed contact form 7 plugin. That is working fine. I just want to hit a post request with JSON on click of submit button. How can I do that ?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Why are you trying to use CF7 for this?

Comment: There is contact us form for customers to get in touch . It sends an email. I just want to add form data to save in database.

Comment: Hey @SunilGarg, are you able to figure out the way to do this ?

Comment: @Mons, Yes! check my answer

Comment: How will i get jsonData here ?

Comment: I created the JSON manually with form data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this

```
on_sent_ok: "$.ajax({  type: "POST",  url: "https://any-url",data: jsonData,success: function(){}})"
```

It should be in one line.

Comment: `on_sent_ok` have been officially removed from Contact Form 7 5.0

Answer (score 0):

If you're just trying to save the data from the forms, you can just use the free plug-in: [Contact Form CFDB7 by Arshid](https://wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-cfdb7/)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).